# Dropping datagridview combobox column without using mouse

Tags: c#, winforms

We recently released a desktop application (for inventory management) and one of our beta testers told me that the application works  fine but there is an issue about datagridview usability; he said that if I could make the combobox column inside the datagridview drops so he can select an item from it's list using keyboard and without having to use mouse to drop down that list.

By doing that, our customers would be able to fill the data into the datagridview in more comfortable way.

The application is a Windows forms application programmed using c#

Comment: Alt+down arrow doesn't work?

Comment: He wants to use down arrow only. If that even possible

Comment: alt+down opens the combobox, then down/up arrow moves between items.

Comment: Another thing is can I make the (cellvaluechanged) event of datagridview works on on every year keystroke and without having to move to next cell?

Comment: You could probably do that but there's a reason it doesn't work that way by default. Are you sure that's what you want? You might have to handle edititngcontrolshowing event. You should probably give it a try and ask a new question.

Comment: Alt+down arrow is the standard and the first thing to do is educate your beta tester about this.

Answer (score 0):

I've made a sample for you, using the Focus ENTER Event and the DroppedDown property of the ComboBox.

**FOR SIMPLE COMBOBOX**

```
for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
    {
      comboBox1.Items.Add(String.Format("Test{0}", i));
    }
    private void comboBox1_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      comboBox1.DroppedDown = true;
    }
```

That way, the combobox will drop when he focuses it.

**FOR DATAGRIDVIEWS**

I've made you a working solution for datagridview :

```
private void dataGridView1_CellEnter(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
 if (e.RowIndex > 0) //this might change for you depending on your header
 {
  if (dataGridView1.SelectedCells[0].GetType().Name = "DataGridViewComboBoxCell")
   {
    dataGridView1.BeginEdit(true);
    ComboBox comboBox = (ComboBox)dataGridView1.EditingControl;
    comboBox.DroppedDown = true;
    }
 }
}
```

It uses the CELLENTER property of datagridview. Don't know if there are better ways to do it but it works.

Comment: What focus event are you referring to? This is a winforms app with a combobox column in a datagridview.

Comment: this.comboBox1.Enter += new System.EventHandler(this.comboBox1_Enter);

This one. It works with WinForm. I just tried it.

Comment: How would you do that to a combobox in a grid column?

Comment: @Crowcoder I've edited my post and made a working solution for gridcolumn